# JavaScript ajax request to servlet call error callback function

Tags: javascript, servlets, callback

I have the following code snippet:

```
$(d).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url : "http://localhost:8080/ProjTest/TestServlet",
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "text",
        data : { test : "test" },
        error : function() {
            alert(1);
        },
        success : function(data) {
            alert(2);
        }
    });
});
```

and in my servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
    Printer out = res.getWriter();
    String paramTest = req.getParameter("test");
    System.out.println("1");
    out.print(paramTest);
    out.close();
    System.out.println("2");
}
```

When I run, in console:

```
1
2
```

But, in javascript call error function !!!

Any idea ???

---

Solved:

I changed the servlet to

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
    res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    Printer out = res.getWriter();
    String paramTest = req.getParameter("test");
    System.out.println("1");
    out.print(paramTest);
    out.close();
    System.out.println("2");
}
```

I added the line:

*res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");*

Comment: Please remove the `Solved` section from the question and also remove `Solved:` from the title. Put the `Solved` section as your answer to your question and then accept the answer. This would help the community to know this question is answered and help follow the standards. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no comma after the `{}` for `data`:

```
dataType : "text",
data : { test : "test" } 
// No comma here --------^
error : function() {
```

It should be like this:

```
dataType : "text",
data : { test : "test" },  // <--- can you see the comma :-D
error : function() {
```

Comment: edit your post to show the correct syntax instead of just pointing it out ;)

Comment: ps.: I saw now that my js code is in mysql server while the servlet is in tomcat ... If I put on the same server, it works! But I want to put on separate servers!! Any idea?